# Create HTML spans for spaces in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given a string of text, I want to create spans for each group of spaces.  How can I do this?

**Example**

```
var myString = "   foo bar"
```

**Result**

```
<p><span class="spaces">   </span>foo<span class="spaces> </span>bar</p>
```

**What I've tried:**

```
var myString = "   foo bar"
var $p = $('p');

for (var i = 0; i < myString.length; i++) {
  if (myString[i] == ' ') {
    $p.append('<span class="spaces"> </span>');
  } else {
    $p.append(myString[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @leo.fcx edited answer to include the loop I'm currently using

Comment: wasn't the error thrown by `myString.forEach` a good clue? Can't use array methods on strings

Comment: @charlietfl - was actually using a library that had a utility for iterating through strings, so just wrote out what I thought it would be. Edited though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple `replace` should do the trick.

```
"   foo bar".replace(/(\s+)/g,'<span class="spaces">$1</span>');
```

Comment: Thanks @joseph - thats much more concise than my loop :)